# In C89, what is the scope of a function name in an 'old-style' function definition?

Tags: c, gcc, clang, standards-compliance, c89

Is the following legal C89?

```
void f(a)
char a[sizeof &f];
{
}
```

My thinking is yes, since the scope of an identifier declared outside any block scope starts immediately after the end of the declarator and extends to the end of the translation unit.  Hence the scope of 'f' includes the declaration-list.

"gcc -pedantic -Wall" accepts it.
"clang -pedantic -Wall" rejects it, as does lcc.

Answer (score 2):

From the C90 Standard (emphasis mine)

> (C90, 6.1.2.1) "Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.**"

<s>So for me also, it's a valid function declaration.</s>

**EDIT:** Devil is in the details (the word *completion*) and after second thought I think that it is not a valid function declaration as the declarator is not complete after `void f(a)`.

```
void f(a)
char a[sizeof &f];
                   ^
```

`^` here marks where the declarator is complete and where `f` scope begins.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the syntax for declarators is pretty explicit.  If the declarator could still be 'incomplete' in some sense until after any declaration-list, I'd expect the standard to say so.  The fact that gcc and clang disagree (even after adding -std=c89) is strange.

Comment: @SebGrindle in C99 (functions with identifier-list form are still valid in c99), a full declarator is defined as (6.7.5p2) a *"A full declarator is a declarator that is not part of another declarator"* Here I think we admit that `void f(a)
char a[sizeof &f];` is a full declarator. In [DR#246](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_246.htm), C Committee does not seem to object as wrong when Clive uses the wording *end of the full declarator* for the completion of the declarator.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to DR#246 (pointing out that someone else also thought the phrase "declarator is complete" is confusing). The committee responded "[..] the current wording is clear enough". Hmmm.